# InTheHand dll, SocketException: The operation completed successfully

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, bluetooth

I'm working on a unity project, and trying to connect the unity by bluetooth.
I'm using InTheHand package, but I face this error printed hundreds of times in the console when running the game.

> SocketException: The operation completed successfully.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
> addressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType,
> System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient.CreateSocket () (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient..ctor
> (InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.BluetoothFactory fcty) (at
> :0) Rethrow as
> PlatformNotSupportedException: 32feet.NET does not support the
> Bluetooth stack on this device.
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient..ctor
> (InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.BluetoothFactory fcty) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient..ctor
> (InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.BluetoothFactory fcty,
> InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint localEP) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.SocketsBluetoothFactory.GetBluetoothClient
> (InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint localEP) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.BluetoothFactory.DoGetBluetoothClient
> (InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint localEP) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient..ctor
> (InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Factory.BluetoothFactory factory,
> InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint localEP) (at
> :0)
> InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient..ctor
> (InTheHand.Net.BluetoothEndPoint localEP) (at
> :0) Helicopter..cctor () (at
> Assets/Scripts/Helicopter.cs:42) Rethrow as
> TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Helicopter'
> threw an exception.

The c# code used in my unity project is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Text;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;


public class bluetooth : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static BluetoothEndPoint EP = new BluetoothEndPoint(BluetoothAddress.Parse("30:D1:6B:F2:5F:40"), BluetoothService.BluetoothBase);
    private static BluetoothClient BC = new BluetoothClient(EP);

    private static BluetoothDeviceInfo BTDevice = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothAddress.Parse("98:D3:B1:FD:87:94"));
    private static NetworkStream stream = null;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Inside start");        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Inside update");
    }
}
```

The error appeared when I added the following lines

> private static BluetoothEndPoint EP = new
> BluetoothEndPoint(BluetoothAddress.Parse("30:D1:6B:F2:5F:40"),
> BluetoothService.BluetoothBase); private static BluetoothClient BC =
> new BluetoothClient(EP);
>
> private static BluetoothDeviceInfo BTDevice = new
> BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothAddress.Parse("98:D3:B1:FD:87:94"));
> private static NetworkStream stream = null;

Any help?